# How do I force a browser to displaying while loading

Tags: wordpress, progress, browser-refresh

I am working in WordPress.  I have several sites set up the exact same way (as far as I can tell).  Most behave as expected.  However, a few of them are such that the browser (all types) does not show the progress of a first-time load or refresh until the page is fully loaded.  It appears idle and then "BLINK", there it is -- fully loaded.

The performance is fine but it is unnerving to have nothing moving until the end.  The header is very clean, no "onLoad" statements, etc., and I do not see any scripting in the PlugIns that would cause this to occur.

Not sure if "forcing" is the solution but I am out of ideas.  I'll take anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, use `flush()`, if ASP.NET use `Response.Flush()`. They're not guaranteed to work though, it [depends on the browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810649/response-flush-only-works-with-firefox) if they will honor your flush request. Try to use jQuery and ajax instead, it can make your app look snappy.

I tried flush on PHP way back 2001, I noticed Mozilla honors flush request I put in long-running loop, there's no plethora of browsers then, unlike today. Not all browsers honor flush requests

**UPDATE**

I tried on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, they all honor the flush request. Just try on IE if it recognize flush too:

```
<table border="1">
   <th>Message</th>
   <% for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) { %>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <%=i %> Hello<br>
        <% System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); %>
        <% Response.Flush(); %>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is great news.  However, we just stepped outside my knowledge area.  These days I program primarily in HTML/CSS and can re-wire WordPress components all day.  I am not at all certain how/where to implement your solution.  I assume just inside the main container DIV.  Sorry, it has been far too long since I did any "real" programming.

Any pointers would be appreciated.